# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using `EF code first 6.1` and  `Sql Server 2008 R2` in my project, I enabeled `Migrations` on my project, when I want to update my `Db` using `Update-database` in `Package Manager Console` I get following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm using `VS 2013, .NET Framework 4`.
Does anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing `SQL Server` fixed the problem.